# Replace bold text in MS Word 2007 with <b>text</b> using C#.NET

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word

I want to search **all bold text occurrences** in **MS Word 2007** document, and replace each bold **"text"** with **"< text >"**

Like following pseudo-code

```
foreach boldText in WordDocument
{
    string replacedText = "< " + boldText + " >";
    WordDocument.replace(boldText ,replacedText );
}

WordDocument.save();
```

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is something like this:

```
private void ReplaceBoldText(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc)
{
    foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng in doc.StoryRanges)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngWord in rng.Words)
        {
            if (rngWord.Bold != 0)
            {
                rngWord.Bold = 0;
                rngWord.Text = "<b>" + rngWord.Text + "</b>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will change every **TEXT** to `<b>TEXT</b>`. If you want to check each character to see if it is bold you would need to iterate through `rngWord.Characters`. You may need some extra work to encapsulate consecutive bold characters, but the basis is as above.

If you are only worrying about whole words then the above will work fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :how to access one particullar StoryRanges.For example i want to display text of one particular StoryRanges of type WdStoryType.wdTextFrameStory.How i get it?Please Help Me...