# Checking if a specific word in a Word document is bold?

Tags: c#, ms-word

How can I check if a specific word in a Word document is bold? I've managed to find the Bold property, but it only returns true on a paragraph if at least **one** of the letters in the paragraph is bold. I need to be able to check if the whole paragraph is bold.

Here's my code so far, using the Word.Interop library.

```
// Open a doc file.
var application = new Application();
var document = application.Documents.Open(path);

// Loop through all words in the document.
foreach (Paragraph paragraph in document.Paragraphs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(paragraph.Range.Text + "");
    Console.WriteLine();
    if (paragraph.Range.Font.Bold > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is bold");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

// Close word.
application.Quit();
```

Comment: you'd need to loop through each word or each letter (depending on precision needed) and check if it's bold as explained here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879880/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879880/replace-bold-text-in-ms-word-2007-with-btext-b-using-c-net).

Comment: Ah, great! Make that as an answer and I'll give you some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd need to loop through each word or each letter (depending on precision needed) and check if it's bold as explained here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879880/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879880/replace-bold-text-in-ms-word-2007-with-btext-b-using-c-net)

Answer (score 3):

Just a little tweak :)

```
if (paragraph.Range.Font.Bold == -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Is bold");
    Console.Read();
}
```