# How to get styles for one word from docx file?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, docx

I can get style of paragraph but I don't know how I can get style for **one** word.

I'm analyzing a text and I'm to get all a formatted words.

**Example.**

Input:

> **Stack Overflow** is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by **Jeff Atwood** and **Joel Spolsky**. It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier question and answer sites such as **Experts-Exchange**. The name for the website was chosen by voting in
>   April 2008 by readers of **Coding Horror**, Atwood's popular programming blog

Output:

> Stack Overflow, Jeff Atwood, Joel Spolsky, Experts-Exchange, Coding Horror.

Additional:
I'm not going to use it for conversion to HTML. I just need get style and use it for estimates of the importance of the word. If word is bold, this mean  that word more important.

Comment: Are you looking for html or docx extraction? They aren't even remotely the same... look into Aspose.Words and HTML Agility Pack depending on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: RandomUs1r, I'm not going to use it for conversion to HTML. I just need get style and use it for estimates of the importance of the word. If word is bold, this mean that word more important.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using for getting the `Paragraph`'s style?
Nevertheless, in order to retrieve that information you'll need to resolve the styling that is applied to the targeted Run element (the one which contains your word).

This can be simple if the styling is just defined directly on the `Run` element (as its child `RunProperties` element), but if it's not then you'll need to resolve the styling by checking the applied style, the style's based style, etc. In short, this is a somewhat complex topic, for a basic introduction I would recommend reading [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2015/09/16/openxml-styles-101-creating-custom-styles-and-understanding-style-inheritance/).

A simple and straightforward solution would be to use a library that can resolve the styling for you, for example [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview):

```
DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load("Sample.docx");

foreach (Run run in document.GetChildElements(true, ElementType.Run))
    if (run.CharacterFormat.Bold)
        Console.WriteLine(run.Text);
```

Also you'll probably want to check out [this reading example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-read-word/301) as well.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. But `GemBox.Document` can read only 20 paragraphs in free trial. So I searched more and find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688863/checking-if-a-specific-word-in-a-word-document-is-bold?rq=1) . I have solved my problem with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

Answer (score 0):

### I solved this problem so:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
...
Application wordApp = new Application();
object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object readOnly = true;
object filename = "...\Test.docx";
Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref miss, ref 
readOnly,...);

List<string> boldList = new List<string>();

foreach (Range rng in doc.StoryRanges)
     foreach (Range rngWord in rng.Words)
         if (rngWord.Bold != 0)
             boldList.Add(rngWord.Text);             

     foreach (var item in boldList)
         Console.WriteLine(item);

     Console.ReadKey();
     wordApp.Quit();
```